# execute docker commands from bash file

Tags: bash, docker, scripting

How can one run docker commands from a bash (sh) script? I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
container= $(docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Names}}" -a | grep testServer | awk '/'$imid'/ { print $1 }');
echo $container
```

but I get a blank for the container.

TIA

Comment: What is `$imid`?

Comment: Sorry - it is a leftover. The goal was to get the container name.

Comment: I'd try with a simple docker command hardcoded until you get the printing working as expected. Then start doing clever grep/awk magic.

Comment: Do you really have a space between `=` and `$` in your code, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the container id is printed to sterr and the `$()` construct only captures stdout.

As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29065117/store-docker-run-command-output-in-bash-variable#comment46365971_29065117), you can use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout, but I'm not quite sure how to work that into your snippet with the grep/awk chaining going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did some testing - as suggested - and found that the following works from bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
container=$(docker ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Names}}" -a | grep testServer  | awk '/'$imid'/ { print $1 }')
echo $container
if [[ $container = *[!\ ]* ]]; then
        echo "found something";
else
        echo "DID NOT find anything";
fi
```

I guess I just had to play around with it some more.

Comment: Maybe a saner way to do it. Unless you need to capture the exact container id to stop or kill it later.

Comment: Yes - I need to use the ID for later - so it works as needed